# SQL Multiple Joining

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I'm trying to join the two table and at the same time getting the value of the certain column by using inner join, I tried joining until the 3rd diagram but when it comes to the fourth it doesn't display the null values, how can I display the values of the 4th column even the null values

here's the code of the SQL

```
betl.user_id,
betl.agent_id,
ah1.parent_id,
ah2.user_id, 
ah3.user_id AS parent_of_agent
       FROM
       wpc16_02.bets_logs betl
          INNER JOIN
          wpc16_02.agent_heirarchy ah1 ON betl.agent_id = ah1.user_id
          INNER JOIN
          wpc16_02.agent_heirarchy ah2 ON ah1.parent_id = ah2.id
          INNER JOIN
          wpc16_02.agent_heirarchy ah3 ON ah2.parent_id = ah3.id
       WHERE
           fight_id = 1930 AND agent_income = 0
```

here's what I'm trying to achieve by using innerjoins:

[image]

Here's the result I got when trying the joining upto the 3rd diagram:

```
user_id | agent_id  | parent_id | user_id_of_parent
15012   | 2212      | 96        |  160
227097  | 22061     | 266       |  64
465174  | 464899    | 126       |  211
505094  | 504767    | 980       |  5358
241158  | 8281      | 18        |  67
463344  | 462715    | 751       |  3420
184396  | 29870     | 502       |  2123
486847  | 43225     | 164       |  234
482120  | 482023    | 4430      |  46469
369628  | 217212    | 8283      |  109697
```

When joining upto 4th diagram:

```
 user_id | agent_id  | parent_id | user_id_of_parent | master_uid
 184396  | 29870     | 502       | 2123              |  160
 482120  | 482023    | 4430      | 46469             |  699
 369628  | 217212    | 8283      | 109697            |  71
 97287   | 93996     | 7332      | 93866             |  3114
 113287  | 113228    | 2714      | 20652             |  4050
 366287  | 361918    | 17603     | 235880            |  234
 439935  | 236147    | 3776      | 40054             |  103
 480201  | 436936    | 1041      | 5761              |  160
 456400  | 456248    | 32901     | 431900            |  240
 502877  | 497592    | 2571      | 20845             |  3918
```

notice the other datas have been removed because when I joined the 4th diagram some of the results are null

Comment: It's good programming practice to qualify all columns - at least when several tables are involved. (For example, which tables do the WHERE clause columns belong to?)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) Simplify if possible, i.e. [mcve].

Comment: here's the first result when I tried joining until to third diagram 
https://prnt.sc/y4e53s


then after joining upto the 4th diagram, i got these result
https://prnt.sc/y4eaah


notice how the other data have been removed because in the table the parent_id has null on the 4th diagram like this
https://prnt.sc/y4efpb

Comment: Sorry, no images. Edit and copy-and-paste the text into the question.

Comment: If you want to include null values, assuming that you mean there is no match on the join predicates, then you need to use an outer join.  In this case I would use a LEFT join.  This also assumes your WHERE clause is not filtering on a column on the table that could have nulls.

Comment: @Bee_Riii can I use right join as I always use the table 2 for joining?

Comment: You need to use `LEFT JOIN` with `Table2` as the left table in all of your joins, because there may be `null`s in `parent_id` column at every level. But for hierarchy building it is better to use recursive CTE, which syntax and support depends on DBMS.

Comment: @astentx so i'll go with left join for all the table 2 that I am using?

Comment: @JianRuizMangampo I think so if you really need just 3 levels of hierarchy and use your current query. For all the hierarchy tree I'll recommend recursion, where you'll need to use the `INNER JOIN` in recursion step to break the infinite loop.

Comment: @astentx fortuanately I got the final result when using the Left join on my query

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `LEFT JOIN`.  It is a little unclear what the exact query is, because your question doesn't have information such as which columns are in which tables.

But the idea is:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM wpc16_02.bets_logs betl LEFT JOIN
     wpc16_02.agent_heirarchy ah1
     ON betl.agent_id = ah1.user_id LEFT JOIN
     wpc16_02.agent_heirarchy ah2
     ON ah1.parent_id = ah2.id LEFT JOIN
     wpc16_02.agent_heirarchy ah3
     ON ah2.parent_id = ah3.id
WHERE betl.fight_id = 1930 AND betl.agent_income = 0
```

This assums that `flight_id` and `agent_income` are from the *first* table.  If they are in one of the hierarchy tables, then the conditions should go in the appropriate `ON` clause.